# Axios and Wufoo: 'Request header field authorization is not allowed' when posting from React

Tags: ajax, axios, cors, wufoo

It's a problem that I've spent hours combing through similar questions here on StackOverflow, but can't seem to find a definitive answer to.

The details are:

- I'm using Axios, in React to connect to Wufoo to post a new form
  submission;
- Wufoo's documentation is legendarily poor, but requires
  Basic authentication;
- When I attempt to submit my post (either from
  localhost or via the AWS instance it builds on), I get an error
  response: `xxx has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field authorization is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.`

Here's my code, I'm clearly setting up the authentication side of things incorrectly, but cannot for the life of me work out what the issue is.

Does anybody have any ideas?

```
    const wufooSubdomain = 'imgforms';
    const formId = 'abcdefg';
    const formAuth = `Basic xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx==`;
    const postURL = `https://${wufooSubdomain}.wufoo.com/api/v3/forms/${formId}/entries.json`;

    axios({
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        Authorization: formAuth,
      },
      method: 'post',
      url: postURL,
      data: formData,
    }).then((result) => {
      console.warn('1) result is ', result);
    });
```

Comment: The API docs a https://wufoo.github.io/docs/ don’t give any indication that the API is intended to be used from frontend JavaScript running in a browser. The docs have examples of making requests using curl and in PHP, Ruby, and Node.js environments, but no similar examples for making requests from frontend code running in browser. That suggests the API is intentionally not CORS-enabled. So your alternatives are to either move the request handling to your backend server-side code, or else to set up some kind of CORS proxy for your frontend code to make the requests through.

Comment: @sideshowbarker: thank you.  That's the same conclusion I've sadly come to.  I've emailed them to clarify, but in the meantime, it's time for me to write a proxy..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @sideshowbarker correctly pointed out, the Wufoo docs don't demonstrate using the front-end to access their API at all.  Sadly their response to my support ticket was:

> "We don't support the API because it is advanced"

However, following the documentation and changing tact slightly I was able to implement a middle-tier in Node to handle the AJAX request.

Comment: Could you share the details of your 'middle-tier in Node' that you came up with?  I'm having the exact same issues described in your initial post, only difference, I'm using Vue/Nuxt.